# How to bind Json Array to IList<t> when it is set deep within the complex type?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to bind the Json 'itemlList' (which is a list) to Ilist ItemList which is deep in the AddQuoteRequestVM model. The Hierarchy is AddquoteRequestVM -> ParcelVM -> Ilist

Controller

```
 public QuoteController()
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AddQuoteRequestVM model)
    {
    }
 }
```

ViewModel

```
public class AddQuoteRequestVM
{
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }
    public DestinationVM PickUpAddress { get; set; }
    public ParcelVM ItemDescription { get; set; }
}

ParcelVM
 public class ParcelVM
 {
    [Required]
    public IList<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
 }

  Item 
    public class Item
   {
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$")]
    public int? Width { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$")]
    public int? Height { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$")]
    public int? Length { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d*\.?\d{1,2}$")]
    [VolumneExist("Volume")]
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$")]
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d*\.?\d{1,3}$")]
    public decimal? Volume { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FreeText { get; set; }

    public byte SelectedPackageType { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery Code

```
 var form = $("#createQuoteForm").serialize();
    var itemList = ko.toJSON(viewModel.ItemList());
    var data = { 'ItemDescription.ItemList' : itemList };
        $.ajax({
            url: "Add",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(form, data);
        });

    });
```

I want to pass in the form data and the Javascript ItemList Array together in one call. At the moment ItemList is returning null. IIf i refactor the code to send form data only, I don't have any issues. Just when I try to send both the form data and the json array.

Any ideas and explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Should it be `var data = { 'ItemDescription.ItemList': itemList };`?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but IList<Item> ItemList is still returning a null.

Comment: Have you checked the request form collection keys. You should be getting something like `ItemDescription.ItemList[0].someProperty`, `ItemDescription.ItemList[1].someProperty` where `someProperty` are the properties of `Item` class (you didn't post `Item` so not sure of the property names)

Comment: No. nothing is shown for ItemDescription

Comment: var itemList = ko.toJSON(viewModel.ItemList()); return json array.

Comment: var itemList = ko.toJSON(viewModel.ItemList()); return json array. but array not in the request form data

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about how Knockout to pinpoint the error.